# Binding checkboxes to object inside of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS.
I am trying to bind this object "Optouts.Spouse" to checkboxes that I am ng-repeating from the object Plans.

SO in my JS I have:

```
$scope.optouts = { spouse: {}, children: {} };
$scope.plans = {mec:true;anotherone:true};
```

And in my Html I have:

```
<span ng-repeat="(plan,x) in plans">{{plan}}
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="optouts.spouse.plan"
          ng-checked="!optouts.spouse.plan"> 
</span>
```

But its not binding to the object. What am I doing wrong? How can I make this work? Thanks!!!

---

There's really not much more to show..

```
 their.plans = {};
 their.toggles = {};
 their.optouts = { spouse: {}, children: {} };
 their.optouts = { spouse: {'mec':true}, children: {} };
 their.spouse = { has:true,
                  firstName: 'Mary',
                  lastName:'Doe',
                  birthDate:'8/10/1989',
                  gender:'Female' }
 their.plans = { mec:true, mr1: true, anotherone:true }
```

Comment: could you provide the json. to improve the answer.

Comment: thx for documentation, i really doesnt. know could iterate over the attrs. i learn something new. by the way i delete answer, cause isnt solve obviusly. if in your question provide the json you need to iterate will excelent t know

Comment: The documentation for the [ng-checked directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) clearly states that it should not be used with `ng-model` directives because it will lead to unexpected behavior. What are you trying to do? The code is so broken that your intention is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are repeating over plans, I imagine you are trying to achieve this:

```
<span ng-repeat="(plan,x) in plans">{{plan}}
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="optouts.spouse.plans[plan]"> 
</span>
```

What you have creates a property on optouts.spouse.plan, but what you want is "map" of true/false values under plan. That said, by using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) with the current value of plan, you can achieve this.

By default, all plans will initially be unchecked as there is no value for them. The checkbox will visually represent true or false, so using `ng-checked` is not necessary. If the checkbox toggles at least once, the given plan will have a true/false value.

If you need to have them set to true, your best bet is to iterate over them in your controller and initialize each with a value of *true*.